# Cannot connect to Kubernetes api on AWS vm's

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have deployed Kubernetes using the link [Kubernetes official page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubeadm/)

I see that Kubernetes is deployed because in the end i got this

```
Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!

To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.
Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node
as root:

  kubeadm join 172.16.32.101:6443 --token ma1d4q.qemewtyhkjhe1u9f --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:408b1fdf7a5ea5f282741db91ebc5aa2823802056ea9da843b8ff52b1daff240
```

when i do kubectl get pods it thorws this error

```
# kubectl get pods 
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6553 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

When I do see the cluster-info it says as follows

```
kubectl cluster-info 
Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:6553
```

But when i see the config it shows as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUN5RENDQWJDZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpNQjRYRFRFNE1EWXlNREEyTURJd04xb1hEVEk0TURZeE56QTJNREl3TjFvd0ZURVRNQkVHQTFVRQpBeE1LYTNWaVpYSnVaWFJsY3pDQ0FTSXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRGdnRVBBRENDQVFvQ2dnRUJBT0ZXCkxWQkJoWmZCQms4bXJrV0w2MmFGd2U0cUYvZkRHekJidnE5TFpGN3M4UW1rdDJVUlo5YmtSdWxzSlBrUXV1U2IKKy93YWRoM054S0JTQUkrTDIrUXdyaDVLSy9lU0pvbjl5TXJlWnhmRFdPTno2Y3c4K2txdnh5akVsRUdvSEhPYQpjZHpuZnJHSXVZS3lwcm1GOEIybys0VW9ldytWVUsxRG5Ra3ZwSUZmZ1VjVWF4UjVMYTVzY2ZLNFpweTU2UE4wCjh1ZjdHSkhJZFhNdXlVZVpFT3Z3ay9uUTM3S1NlWHVhcUlsWlFqcHQvN0RrUmFZeGdTWlBqSHd5c0tQOHMzU20KZHJoeEtyS0RPYU1Wczd5a2xSYjhzQjZOWDB6UitrTzhRNGJOUytOYVBwbXFhb3hac1lGTmhCeGJUM3BvUXhkQwpldmQyTmVlYndSWGJPV3hSVzNjQ0F3RUFBYU1qTUNFd0RnWURWUjBQQVFIL0JBUURBZ0trTUE4R0ExVWRFd0VCCi93UUZNQU1CQWY4d0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUFEZ2dFQkFDTFBlT0s5MUdsdFJJTjdmMWZsNmlINTg0c1UKUWhBdW1xRTJkUHFNT0ZWWkxjbDVJZlhIQ1dGeE13OEQwOG1NNTZGUTNEVDd4bi9lNk5aK1l2M1JrK2hBdmdaQgpaQk9XT3k4UFJDOVQ2S1NrYjdGTDRSWDBEamdSeE5WTFIvUHd1TUczK3V2ZFhjeXhTYVJJRUtrLzYxZjJsTGZmCjNhcTdrWkV3a05pWXMwOVh0YVZGQ21UaTd0M0xrc1NsbDZXM0NTdVlEYlRQSzJBWjUzUVhhMmxYUlZVZkhCMFEKMHVOQWE3UUtscE9GdTF2UDBDRU1GMzc4MklDa1kzMDBHZlFEWFhiODA5MXhmcytxUjFQbEhJSHZKOGRqV29jNApvdTJ1b2dHc2tGTDhGdXVFTTRYRjhSV0grZXpJRkRjV1JsZnJmVHErZ2s2aUs4dGpSTUNVc2lFNEI5QT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
    **server: https://172.16.32.101:6443**
```

Even telnet shows that there is a process running on 6443 but not on 6553 
how can change the port and how can I fix the issue??

Any help would be of great use

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue it is because of the firewall in the machine I could join nodes to the cluster once I allowed traffic via port 6443. I didn't fix the issue with this post but for beginners use this [K8's on AWS](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/DevOps-Kubernetes-III-Kubernetes-on-Linux-with-kubeadm.php&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1530265751951000&usg=AFQjCNHMxjNrFJ7CBGaranLBvKr84_qFrA) for a better idea.

Thanks for the help guys...!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your last kubectl config interferes with the previous clusters configurations.

It is possible to have settings for [several different clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) in one `.kube/config` or in separate files.
But in some cases, you may want to manage only the cluster you've just created.

**Note:** After tearing down the exited cluster using `kubeadm reset` followed by initializing fresh cluster using `kubeadm init`, new certificates will be generated. To operate the new cluster, you have to update kubectl configuration or replace it with the new one.

To clean up old `kubectl` configurations and apply the last one, run the following commands:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.kube
unset KUBECONFIG

# Check if you have KUBECONFIG configured in profile dot files and comment or remove it.

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

It gives you up-to-date configuration for the last cluster you've created using kubeadm tool.

**Note:** You should copy kubectl configuration for all users accounts which you are going to use to manage the cluster.

[Here](http://jeffmendoza.github.io/kubernetes/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file.html) are some examples of how to manage config file using the command line.

Comment: @vasI have tried that but still, the issue persists I can see the containers up and running but can't see the pods running

# kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 172.16.32.101, not 127.0.0.1

Comment: What settings the file /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf contains? Especially what IP's and ports for the apiserver are there? What options did you use during cluster initialization?

Comment: i could fix it but im now getting this error

# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.96.0.0/12 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=127.0.0.1

$ kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
any idea on this ??

Comment: I'm not using kops I'm just trying regular deployment and couldn't get these things up and running.

Comment: This command should be enough to correctly initialize the cluster: # kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16  ##Do not forget to update your .kube/config file as recommended by kubeadm.